# How to execute sql query when debugging a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, procedure, temp-tables

I'm debugging a stored procedure on SQL Server 2008 and I have this:

```
INSERT INTO #tempTable (ID, Name)
  SELECT ID, Name FROM dbo.MYTABLE WHERE dbo.MYTABLE.Old >= 15
```

How can I view the data into #tempTable on Debug time?

Comment: Query temp db and find your table, but it will have changed name, something like tempTable00000001

Comment: With a select statement, usually.   Why?

Comment: Specify what you want to achieve, your stored procedure insert data to temp table and you want to see it from another session? If not add just simple `SELECT * FROM #tempTable` after this, alter procedure and move on, after debugging comment or delete it.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server Management Studio, you can't execute query directly while debugging stored procedure, and that's still not implemented(I think). You can only view the local variables value in Local Debug Window.

There are some work around to see temp table values while in Debugging mode:-

1) In the stored procedure, after insert data into #temptable, add this line of code to get temptable values in xml table varriable where you want to see temptable values. Then you can check the values in Local Debug window in xml format

```
  --inserting data into temp table
  INSERT INTO #tempTable (ID, Name)
  SELECT ID, Name FROM dbo.MYTABLE WHERE dbo.MYTABLE.Old >= 15

  --to see records of temp table
  DECLARE @temptable XML 
  SET @temptable = (SELECT * FROM #@temptable FOR XML AUTO)
```

2) You can convert local temp table(`#temptable`) to global temptable(`##temptable`), so when you insert date in temp table, you can open new query window, and able to see global temp table records using select query.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post describes how to access a temporary table from another session:
http://web.archive.org/web/20180409190701/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/14/viewing-another-session-s-temporary-table.aspx

Alternative you can use two ## in the table name to make the table globally accessible from other sessions: ##tempTable (The table might be locked for reading while your insert is running)

Answer (score -1):

Even though SQL Server Management Studio has some debugging functions , but I find them pretty useless.

I don't think there are any debugging tools out there for SQL Server like Visual Studio, which will give you a step by step information at runtime.

The way normally developers debug sql server code is to use print statement, for stored procedures take the sp definition out declare a variable for each parameter that procedure expects , hardcode the values for variables and execute smaller logical blocks of code to see what's going on where.